# Robocopy error while copying from Dynamic View

Tags: clearcase-ucm, robocopy, snapshot-view

I have an issue which has been bothering me for the past couple of months.
I use a Dynamic View of UCM Clearcase to copy latest source code to the local disk. I then compile the source code and generate Installshield packages etc. I use Robobopy for copying the files.

The Robocopy fails to copy and hangs. This happens 2-3 times a week. So it has become a Nightly Build workflow nightmare. Luckily, yesterday, I saw an error displayed by Robocopy. It was something like:

> ERROR 64: The specified network name no longer exists

I Googled and found that this may be caused due to:

> 1) Anti-Virus
>
> 2) Improper network hardware configuration

The other important thing is that I do not see any network issues during any other operation related to Clearcase or other software.

I have been pushing the idea of using snapshot views, after VonC's recommendation, for compilation but the management seems reluctant because:

> 1) Other teams too have the same setup where they copy from Dynamic
>   views
>
> 2) They face less than 5% copy failures
>
> 3) Copying from Dynamic view seems to be a best practice according to
>   other teams and I am asked to follow it.

I wanted to know if anyone has faced such an issue.

I wanted some points which can help me in convincing the management to move towards snapshot views for compilation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use a Dynamic View of UCM Clearcase to copy latest source code to the local disk.

An easier way would be to use a *snapshot* UCM view (even if the other teams are using dynamic ones), that you would `cleartool update` each time you need those files locally.

The config spec of that snapshot view will be exactly the same than the dynamic one, and you can tweak the load rules in order to load only what you need.
That doesn't prevent use to use Robocopy and copy those files to the right place.

The idea is to avoid any hang issue, and avoid even those 5% copy failure.
Dynamic views are good for small consultation purpose, or for configuration update (rebase), or merges (delivers), but not for massive read operations.

Comment: Hi VonC: Are there any specific issue that I need to keep in mind while using snapshot views? The code base is 3.5 GB with around 30,000 files. Do you see an update operation taking too long in such cases?

Comment: @msiyer if you can make your snapshot root directory *directly* where you was robocopy'ing, you would skip that step. In that case, I can *guarantee* a cleartool update, which is incremental, will be faster than a robocopy through a dynamic view,  even if the robocopy is also incremental.